# What's it called when anime and manga chooses not to show nipples but make it as erotic as possible

Tags: tropes

What's it called when anime and manga chooses not to show nipples but make it as erotic as possible? I recall in *No Game No Life*, they did this in their match-up against Jabril the Mugol.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think:

I believe that would depend on the extent of eroticism being shown, although I think the word you're looking for is simply 'censored'. If they are

> Anime that contain a lot of sexual humor but no outright pornography

then they can be classified as an [Ecchi anime](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/lexicon.php?id=17) that is censored. *No Game, No Life* is one of them.

This might be confusing as some ecchi anime like *Araiya-san!: Ore to Aitsu ga Onnayu de!?* are still classified as ecchi yet one who does not know its classification might say that it is hentai. If you watch it, you'll see what I mean. In which case, I think it would be less confusing to use borderline hentai for ecchi anime which is almost but not classified as hentai. 'Borderline hentai' anime which censors nipples include *Kiss x Sis*.

Both terms, ecchi and borderline hentai, may or may not censor nipples depending on the anime. **As far as I know, there is no specific term for an ecchi or borderline hentai anime that is censored.**